# Problem installing LambertW package for R

Tags: r, package, failed-installation

I'm trying to install the LambertW package for R (or any package that will give me the Lambert W function). Everytime I try:

`install.packages("LambertW")`

I get this output...

```
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
Error in read_r_config(sprintf("%sFLAGS", cxx), envir = NULL)[[1]] : 
  subscript out of bounds
Calls: source_file -> eval -> eval
Execution halted
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘RcppParallel’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/3.6/site-library/RcppParallel’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘RcppParallel’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘RcppParallel’ is not available for package ‘lamW’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/3.6/site-library/lamW’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘lamW’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘lamW’ is not available for package ‘LambertW’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/3.6/site-library/LambertW’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘LambertW’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/4m/qkbb2hwd1t12v_11mjcphv300000gn/T/RtmpcUm3LQ/downloaded_packages’
```

Then if I try to load it using library I get this

```
library("LambertW")

Error in library("LambertW") : there is no package called ‘LambertW’
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Can you change the repo

Comment: I'd think the *"invalid active developer path"* and *"missing xcrun"* are the likely culprits. I suggest you (re)install `xcode`, then try to install your packages again.

Comment: Hi, @botinky. I'm the author of the lamW package on which LambertW depends. If you just want the real-valued LambertW function, lamW is enough. However, lamW itself has a dependency on RcppParallel. Have you tried installing RcppParallel by iteself and then lamW?

Comment: @botinky, did you ever get this to work?

Comment: @Avraham yes I did! But I'm afraid it's so long ago I can't remember exactly how I got it working. It may have been the xcode issue mentioned by r2evans